# Selecting and ordering from 3 different tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a code which selects 10 of the users who have "earned" money ordering by the price desc.
I have been using this query:

```
SELECT products.seller, 
SUM(products.price * (1 - reseller.fee / 100)), 
COUNT(*) 
FROM products
INNER JOIN reseller ON reseller.username = products.seller
WHERE (products.seller!= 'MYSITE') 
AND products.sold=1 
AND products.sellerpaid=0 
AND products.username != 'None' 
GROUP BY products.seller
ORDER BY SUM(products.price * (1 - reseller.fee / 100)) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

By this I get:

```
uploaded_by  SUM()  COUNT()
 username    10.00     2
 username1   11.00     3

....
```

Which works absolutely fine,
but now I have another table, products1
and that contains something more that's why I cannot merge them, so I want to get the same results as in the first one but fetching the price of all products from this table as well.
I have tried LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, and many others but still can't do it correctly.

Please do not tell me to read more about joins because I already have, just can't do it, if you can come up with a solutions then post it if possible.

Also if there is anything that you do not understand, please comment so I can give further explanations.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you want to retrieve?

Comment: What is the relationship between `products` and `products1`? If they're one-to-one, you can just use an `INNER JOIN` to fetch information from it.

Comment: right, i forgot to tell,     its the same date, seller, count() and price
WHERE clause has to be the same as well.

Comment: also i cannot use INNER JOIN because inner join gets only information that matches from all tables if i am right. @Barmar

Comment: @Fokker That's why I said it would be used if they're one-to-one. If you provide more details, we should be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fokker

If Im not wrong, you can use an UNION of both tables. I dont know if MySQL support this functionality, but SQLServer does:

```
SELECT tmp.seller, 
SUM(tmp.price * (1 - tmp.fee / 100)), 
COUNT(*) 
FROM (select p.seller, p.price, r.fee from products p
INNER JOIN reseller r ON r.username = p.seller
WHERE (p.seller!= 'MYSITE') 
AND p.sold=1 
AND p.sellerpaid=0 
AND p.username != 'None'
UNION ALL
select p1.seller, p1.price, r1.fee from products p1
INNER JOIN reseller r1 ON r1.username = p1.seller
WHERE (p1.seller!= 'MYSITE') 
AND p1.sold=1 
AND p1.sellerpaid=0 
AND p1.username != 'None') tmp
GROUP BY tmp.seller
ORDER BY SUM(tmp.price * (1 - tmp.fee / 100)) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Hope help you

PD. Sorry for my bad english hehehehe

Comment: You sir, are a LIFESAVER.
Thank you so much ;)

Comment: Wait a minute, i think there is something that is wrong there,
Because it is not giving me the correct values,
Also, what does union do if products from both tables have the same ID ?

Comment: Hey partner!! Why do you unselect my answer as correct? I'm new here and you robbed me!! Hahahahaha! 
I answer the question you ask, you just ask for merge the information with other table. I dont know the information of your tables or if they have the same ID (if that is the case, I already modify the answer with an UNION ALL, is less heavy that the query you posted)
Give me back my answer as correct!! Hahahahaha!
PD: Sorry again for my bad english

Comment: hahha but its not correct tho :v
It gave me a lot of miscalculations and wrong details.
However there was no mistake with the query
AND the problem was not at UNION ALL, you can check the difference from the version that I made and yours.
Anyways you solved the problem so thanks and have fun.

And.. Your english is fine, at least understandable.

Answer (score 1):

By playing around with some queries, i managed to fix this problem.
The solution is:

```
SELECT * FROM (select p.seller, sum(p.price * (1-r.fee/100)) as sumi, count(*) as counti from products p
INNER JOIN reseller r ON r.username = p.seller
WHERE (p.seller!= 'MYSITE') 
AND p.sold=1 
AND p.resellerpaid=0 
AND p.username != 'None'  
GROUP BY p.seller
UNION
select p1.seller, sum(p1.price * (1-r1.fee/100)) as sumi, count(*) as counti from products1 p1
INNER JOIN reseller r1 ON r1.username = p1.seller
WHERE (p1.seller!= 'MYSITE') 
AND p1.sold=1 
AND p1.resellerpaid=0 
AND p1.username != 'None' GROUP BY p1.seller) tmp
ORDER BY sumi DESC
```

I thank @gerardo-hiram-vega-cabrera For his answer, his answer really helped me figure out how UNION works, i couldnt figure that out after reading a lot of crap found on google.

Thanks stackoverflow ;)